# Facebook share button erratic behavior with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I have two issues trying to integrate Facebook Share buttons in my SPA application. The application displays two lists of articles, those posted y other people and those posted by me. Each of these two lists are presented separately by clicking at one of two buttons at the top of the page. I'm using `ng-show` to achieve this (meaning, there are two `$scope` variables that are set to **true** or **false** by these buttons, such that if **$scope.Others_Posts** is set to **true**, the posts from others are being shown; the opposite for my own posts).

The first problem is that the first time I click on the Facebook share button in, say, the others' posts view, I get the Facebook login window as needed. As long as I remain in the same view (others' posts in this example), popping of the Facebook login works ok. If I switch to the other view (my posts), then the share button does not appear anymore. Nothing I do helps (like going back to the first view). If, on the other hand, I switch to the second view **before** invoking the share, it also works as long as I don't switch view.
Summarizing, if I click on the share button in one of the two views, as soon as I switch view (from others' posts to mine or vise-versa), the share button stops appearing.

This is what I'm using:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
        aria-haspopup="true" 
        aria-expanded="false" 
        style="width:100%;height:40px;text-align:left">
    <div id="fb-root" style="width:100%;height:0px;margin:-10px 0 0 0 "></div>
    <script>
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
        );
    </script>
    <style>
        .fb-share-button
        {
            transform: scale(1.5);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
            -o-transform: scale(1.5);
            -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform-origin: top left;
            -ms-transform-origin: top left;
            -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
            -moz-transform-origin: top left;
            -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
        }
    </style>


    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="{{Get_Path_for_Facebook(One_Article)}}" data-layout="button"></div>
</button>
```

Note that I am wrapping the standard code from Facebook into a button because I have other actions to offer to the user.

My second problem is more AngularJS oriented. The URL I need to share includes parameters that are calculated/built remotely. Since there may be tens or hundreds of entries in the list, I want to invoke the remote service only when it is needed (i.e. when the user wishes to share a particular entry). This is suppose to be done by the function `Get_Path_for_Facebook(One_Article)` which is to be invoked when the user clicks on the share button of a particular entry.

The issue appears to be the asynchronous behavior of the promise created when invoking the service (i.e. the function `Get_Path_for_Facebook` issues a HTTP request with a promise that returns the needed parameters, but this takes place too late).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Facebook's `sharer.php`. Basic concept:

HTML

```
<button ng-click="share(selected)">Share</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.share = function share(selected) {
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://your.url/&t=' + selected.id, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
    // anything else you want to do when clicking the share button
}
```

You can remove the FB SDK as well, if you're not using it for anything else.

Comment: Thank you @JohnSmith. I'll try it and let you know. One question though:  Does my site need to be known to Facebook, I mean, does it have to be a Facebook-registered application (with its allocated ID?

Comment: It's been a while since I last used it, but as far as I can remember, no, you don't need to register anything.

Comment: OK. Will try it. Also, since the whole thing is passed to the control of my Javascipt,. if it works, it will solve both issues. Will update you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but just realized that there is one more question to be asked: the URL I need to pass to Facebook also includes parameters, so it would look something like `www.Mytestsite.com?par1=abcd&par2=defg`. How should I include it within a URL that has parameters itself? Should I enclosed in quotation (like `"www.Mytestsite.com?par1=abcd&par2=defg"`)?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's supported anymore. Perhaps you can try using the share dialog then: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog, specifically the URL redirection method, but I have no experience with that, I'm sorry.